# Jar signing in Netbeans IDE 7.3 produces "The signer's certificate chain is not validated"

Tags: java, certificate, java-web-start, jar-signing

I have a PVK and SPC file and want to use them to sign jar files from the Netbeans IDE 7.3. My application will be deployed from Java Web Start.

I combined them into a PFX file using keytool.

> "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Bin\pvk2pfx.exe" -pvk
>   joy.pvk -spc joy.spc -pi happy -pfx joyful.pfx

I found the Alias.

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\keytool" -v -list -storetype
>   pkcs12 -keystore joyful.pfx > abc.txt

Then I converted the pfx to Java Keystore from the steps in this Comodo [link](https://support.comodo.com/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=1283)

> "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\keytool" -importkeystore
>   -srckeystore joyful.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore joyful.jks -deststoretype JKS

The IDE (Project Properties | Deployment | Signing certificate) asks for keystore path, password, Key Alias and Key Password. I fill it in.

Now I do a clean and build but notice this message:

> Warning:  The signer's certificate chain is not validated.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem - importing and exporting again pfx file with full certificate chain helped me. For details, you can look at my post: http://jehy.ru/articles/2013/12/12/warning-the-signers-certificate-chain-is-not-validated/